# How to deploy a rest service locally using eclipse, and what client should be used

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, rest, client

Current setup: I have a java project in eclipse which is trying to implement REST services, and I intend to deploy it on the eclipse tomcat server, and I want to TEST this webservice.

So everything I am reading has either too many steps, with technologies/frameworks I'm not familiar with (jersey for instance), or is too old to trust the source (the way of doing this may have changed/improved), several of the higher stackoverflow are like this.

What I want to learn is what is needed to deploy a service in a local server, tomcast (what steps, what type of files are required (wsdl and war are two that I've seen being used in other projects, but do not know what is needed in this case), and then what rest client to use to make request to my service.

**Example**: I've just been told that for SOAP, one possibility would be to use the "create web service" of eclipse with the java where the service is defined, and that gives you a wsdl file. That file goes to Tomcat instance, and (could) go to a client called SOAPUI where you create a project, use that same wsdl, and make petitions to the tomcast server, that way you can test it.

I am not able right now to see an equivalent to this, for REST. I've seen war is used, and I can generate it, but, is it the same idea? I see so many blogs explaining how to CREATE the rest client, with code, and I just want to test my service, simulating a real case.

With what I've read so far, there are so many options I'm not really getting it (other than, of course, it is possible to implement everything. **I just want to test what the webservices, and to learn how and why is it done that way if possible).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of web-services:

1. **SOAP** Web-services (XML based, strict formatting/processing rules)
2. **REST** based (much simpler, uses HTTP GET/POST/PUT verbs for operations)

For a head start, you should go ahead with REST based web-services.

Java provides libraries to implement both kinds of web-services. The REST web-services library for Java is called JAX-RS (JAXB/Jersey). It is an easy to learn, very robust and easy to manage library. You can create simple as well as complicated applications with ease using JAX-RS. It also complements your requirement as you can very easily implement a RESTful application locally, deploy it on Tomcat and start playing with it. You don't need to use any kind of special framework (Spring/Play) to write a program that provides REST based CRUD application, just start the Eclipse IDE, import JAX-RS libraries and create a simple CRUD application under 30 minutes. 
*(Although Spring/Play provide extensive support/integration of JAX-RS).*

Here are some of the resources to help you get started with JAX-RS:

- [RESTful Web Services - Java (JAX-RS)](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/restful/restful_jax_rs.htm)
- [Javabrains - Developing Applications with JAX-RS](https://javabrains.io/courses/javaee_jaxrs)

JAX-RS API provides both Server and Client libraries to build a REST Server to process RESTful requests and a REST-client to consume responses generated from a Server.

***Pro Tip: Stop reading too much. Start building NOW!***

PS. I don't know why other answers are suggesting a Spring Boot solution, because that thing in itself is a bit complicated for beginners and covers up a lot of inner details of how RESTful web-services work in Java.

Comment: I recommend spring boot for beginners because it focuses on the bare minimum number of tasks to create a Restful webservice and lets the beginner learn about how to make them quickly.  Its important to show beginners how to do something before explaining how it works.

Comment: @MatthewFontana I agree. But unless that beginner has a good knowledge of web-application development in Java, let it be in servlets or a framework, it is usually difficult to set up Spring Boot and an overhead to understand how Spring Boot in itself works.

Comment: I would agree with that statement regarding most Spring frameworks, however, Spring Boot's automatic configuration removes all of the boilerplate involved in setting up a spring application so you can simply focus on the task at hand.  In terms of setup a full spring boot application can actually be sent in a single tweet.  Which makes it really easy to digest.  On the contrast I do strongly agree if you were to use Spring MVC directly the extra hour of configuration involved would definitely not be worth it.

Comment: @InamTaj SOAP is able to pass values with a request, and obtain values based on wsdl. How can you do the same with rest?

Answer (score 3):

got to https://start.spring.io  download springboot project with whatever dependencies u want.write a rest api.run it.test it using postman client which will be available on chrome extensions

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit generic, but I will try to give you the absolute simplest way to get a web service up and running.  I recommend using Spring Boot to accomplish this.  You can get the project up and running on spring boot with 2 very simple files.  I will link the starter page here which shows you that: http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/

If you are having trouble generating the project you can also use: https://start.spring.io/  This will help you generate the project first which you can then port into eclipse.

This will let you run a standalone restful webservice as a Jar file.  If you need it to run on tomcat I recommend changing your pom.xml file to be packaging war and add the dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Yes I know it is too generic but I'm lacking the vocabulary or worse yet, I mix things up. I've only seen a bit of REST but not enough to express what I'm doing/what I want to do, clearly. About that spring thing, to see if I'm understanding properly. I DO have a project, in eclipse, coded in java. What would that spring project be used for? Same matter, or it adds something? (for instance I might have the pom and web.xml wrongly set up, but as of right now I'm not sure, because I'm not running the webservice, and not testing how it behaves, which is what I want).

Comment: It looks like you are getting a bit overwhelmed with the number of available options out there.  There are tons of ways of making webservices and hundreds if not thousands of vocabulary words.  In order to not get overwhelmed I recommend picking a tutorial and a single methodology to start with.  If you would like a walk-through to give you a hand this one is pretty good: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/